# Django errors when running via Virtual Environment: Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Tags: django

Django errors when running via Virtual Environment: Exception in thread Django-main-thread. I am doing this in Venv and not sure where I am going wrong? Can someone please help?

Initially, I ran into this issue when I accidentally upgraded Django when PyCharm prompted it but after that, I created a Venv and moved my files over but the error seems to be persistent.

```
(venv) users-MacBook-Pro:myproject $ python manage.py runserver
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Performing system checks...

    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
        return self._engines[alias]
    KeyError: 'django'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/Users/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 79, in check_dependencies
        for engine in engines.all():
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
        return [self[alias] for alias in self]
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
        return [self[alias] for alias in self]
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
        engine = engine_cls(params)
      File "/Users/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
        options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
        libraries = get_installed_libraries()
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
        for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
        module = import_module(entry[1])
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 15, in <module>
        from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 20, in <module>
        from django.test.client import encode_multipart
      File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 23, in <module>
        from django.test import signals
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 149, in __enter__
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 94, in acquire
    _frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 4373516432
```

Comment: try removing all pyc files

Comment: It workes. Thanks a ton!